# How does primitive types in Javascript have methods and Properties?

Tags: javascript

```
var num1 = new Number(5);
typeof(num1); //returns "object"
num1.toString(); //returns "5"
```

I understand that `num1` being an object has a property `.__proto__` via which it  gets access to `.toString()` by going down the prototype (`.__proto__`) chain.

```
var num = 5;
typeof(num); //returns "number"
num.toString(); //returns "5"
```

In above case, num is a primitive type `number`. It means that it won't have any properties and methods. Then how's it able to get access to `.toString()` method?

Comment: Because when you do `.toString` it's not actually a primitive any more. If you're calling methods on a primitive, JS will wrap it into an object and then discard the object. It's sort of equivalent to doing `var temp = new Number(num); temp.toString()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It means that it won't have any properties and methods.

Javascript has a property called coercion when it comes to primitives; it silently converts the primitive to any object and then accesses the prototype method of the newly constructed number object.

Comment: so, what's the point of having primitives instead of just objects? given that all primitives (except of null, undefined... maybe?) will be coerced...

Comment: @ThiagoDias There is none, and it was considered a mistake in hindsight by the designers. It was done to make JavaScript more similar to Java, while the original goal was a language where everything is an object - and the "primitives" would just have been (immutable) objects. No wrapper types, no distinction between `String()` and `new String()`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript coerces between primitives and objects. In this case number converts to object in order to access to string.

You can get the object using

```
//tweaking the to string
Number.prototype.toString = function() {
    return typeof this;
}
var num = 5;
typeof(num); 
num.toString(); //returns "object"
```